# How to make webview change url automatically?

Tags: android, url, dynamic, webview

Problem is that `url` changes every day 
from

> https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=757

to

> https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=758

and so on....

```
package com.example.comunicatavariicompaniaaquaserv;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;  

public class tutorialOne extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.avarii);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//enable java content
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);//enable zoom-out page
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Se incarca datele...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }

    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,   
        String failingUrl)                                                          
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        });

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=757");
    } 
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? just give the correct url in webView.loadUrl()

Comment: I don't want to do it every day. It should be automated. Besides if I publish the apk on google play that means that every day I would have to republish it and that is just awfull..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your use case? How do you get this URL? Do you have to hard code the URL? What triggers the change?

I'll recommend that you get the URL dynamically and pass it to the WebView. If you know when the URL is going to change, or if you can always get the latest URL with a unique identification, you can load the URL in your WebView after you get the latest URL.

Comment: The url is changed once a day, after a new message is posted on the website. I would like it if the proces would be automated so that I wouldn't have to manually change the url every day.

Comment: How to get url dynamically and pass it to webview within my code?

Comment: @dodialfaed Apparently, you need to find out how many new messages are posted on the website, then you could automate the process. Is there any web service to do so? Or you could create your own. Essentially you can have a cron job running monitoring new messages on the website, and store that information in a database. When your app is up, you could go pull that information and calculate the correct URL. It can be automated, but you need to the app how.

Comment: @dodialfaed if the URL only changes once a day(say day 0 it's ....757 and day 10 it's .....767), you can probably save the URL in SharedPreferences along with the initial time. Then when the app is open, you see how many days have passed since when you saved the URL, thus you could change it.

Answer (score 0):

loadUrl(String url) and load*(..)  on WebView are the functions that would let  you to set the url dynamically. The following Activity does it. It has two buttons, "click to go to google" and "click to go to yahoo" , when clicked , the loadUrl() method is called to update the WebView.

So for any change in the url , call the loadUrl() function with the argument and you are done.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }*/
        final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Button b= (Button)  findViewById(R.id.google);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

            }
        });
        Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yahoo);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use  this  code

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url.replace("https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=757", "https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=758"));
            return false;
        }
```